# Loading wallet crashes bitcoin core wallet

Tags: wallet.dat

When trying to load a wallet I last used in 2017 December, in bitcoin core wallet 0.21.0 x64, the UI exits abruptly, last few lines in the debug.log shows the following:

```
2021-02-10T07:20:22Z Using wallet d:\btdata\dijitalparaciklar.dat
2021-02-10T07:20:22Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=d:\btdata\database ErrorFile=d:\btdata\db.log
2021-02-10T07:20:22Z init message: Loading wallet...
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] Wallet File Version = 130000
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] Keys: 0 plaintext, 214 encrypted, 214 w/ metadata, 214 total. Unknown wallet records: 0
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] Wallet completed loading in 175ms
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z init message: Rescanning...
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] Rescanning last 173423 blocks (from block 496540)...
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] Rescan started from block 0000000000000000009e546a2183eb90aea183bd153f2d7b3c34f67b4aa6abc5...
2021-02-10T07:20:23Z [dijitalparaciklar.dat] AddToWallet 0f1162a63b3ae14a3bc8907f8edbb57e392fc5dfadfe866de0eb5d470f7504df 
2021-02-10T07:20:25Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=669964, peer=2 (full-relay)
```

Windows records the crash as follows:

Faulting application name: bitcoin-qt.exe, version: 0.21.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Faulting module name: bitcoin-qt.exe, version: 0.21.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000038ca40
Faulting process id: 0x5128
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6ff7aa101f703
Faulting application path: D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe
Report Id: 49909fad-f4bd-4f8c-9423-a585cbeaba86
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Any ideas why this could be happening? db.log is empty btw..

Comment: I am having the same problem (with different dates and using the cli version). [My post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102659/upgrading-converting-bitcoin-core-wallet-between-platforms). Your situation seems to indicate that the problem I am having is not related to platform or gui vs cli, which is helpful (at least to me). So thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this file: ErrorFile=d:\btdata\db.log

Errors are logged in there. You are viewing the debug logs which will not print any error.

Comment: Thanks, checked that file however it's empty as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Did you try reindex and rescan option ?

Comment: I tried rescan but not reindex, will try that..

Comment: --rescan --reindex allowed me to load the wallet. Thank you!